# How to reload a page after content has been logged using implicit fluch

Tags: javascript, reload, flush

Heres my problem I have a piece of code which traverses a queue to get database content and outputs to the browser using implicit flush, once the end of the code is reached I need to refresh the page so the next item in the queue is processed. I tried the header command at first but obviously this didn't fail as the rendered page has content. I also tried adding a javascript document ready with location.reload(true); in it but it doesn't trigger. So I guess this file I wish to be recursive while items are in the queue. Heres a simplified version of the dequeue file

```
include( './dbcnn.php' );
// Autoloader
include( './autoloader.php' );

@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
ob_implicit_flush(1);

$startTime = time();
if ( $myQueue->size() > 0 ) {
    $is_locked = @mkdir(DOCROOT . '/logs/eclipse.lock');
}
if ( $is_locked === true && $myQueue->size() > 0 ) {
    $action = "Started";
    echo $action . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";

    $item = $myQueue->bottom();
    $data = unserialize( $item, ['BackupQueue'] );
    $clientid = $data[ 'id' ];
   ...
        [run tasks echoing results as they finish]
        [remove from queue and remove locked flag file]
   ...

    // Tasks have finished get the next one item from the queue, if there is one.
    //header("Refresh:1");
    echo '<script> $( document ).ready( function() { location.reload( true ); } ); </script>';
}
```

How can i just reload the page when all actions have finished? Thids section of code is currently attached to a cron that runs every minute but it seems wasteful as the queue spends 66% of the day empty (it runs some overnight tasks)

As I say it gets to the end and stops and if using the header command it says headers already sent, the script tag is there in the page content. I do of cpourse realise i could place the whole thing in a while loop or something but why doesn't this work?  I believe placing the reload in the header section will just reload the page without running the tasks (due to the flush?)

thanks

** EDIT ** Solution below from mrcoder worked (window.location.reload();)

Comment: `window.location.reload()` didn't work? please try removing `$( document ).ready( function()`.

Comment: Ah yes using the full window.location.reload() worked whereas  location.reload() didn't

Comment: Great! Happy Coding.